# How to run macro on all files in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that will run on all Excel files in a folder and copy columns with certain headers then paste then to a new sheet titled "ExtractedColumns").

I ran this macro on a small folder (four Workbooks) and successfully got the data onto the ExtractedColumns sheet.

When I ran the macro on a folder with 60 files (which included the four files from my successful sample set), it skipped some workbooks and seems to have wrapped around itself. The last file's extracted columns appear at the beginning, and columns from the first few files (including the sample ones that ran successfully earlier) didn't appear.

I'm thinking the problem is the code iterating through the folder.

```
Sub AllFiles()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = 'I put the path name here

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
Do While filename <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)

    'Macro from below goes here

    Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1).Value = filename
    wb.Close
    filename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here's the complete macro:

```
Dim curr As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Variant
Dim n As Long
Dim found As Boolean
Dim FirstRow As Range

found = False

For i = 3 To 30
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "C")) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each curr In Range("A" & i, "Z" & i)
    If InStr(1, curr.Value, "Protein name", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "description", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "Common name", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns (version 2)").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not found Then
    For Each curr In Range("A" & i, "Z" & i)
        If InStr(1, curr.Value, "protein", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next              
End If

For Each curr In Range("A" & i, "Z" & i)
    If InStr(1, curr.Value, "accession", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "Uniprot", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "IPI") > 0 Then
        Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each curr In Range("A" & i, "Z" & i)
    If (InStr(1, curr.Value, "residue", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or curr.Value = "Position" Or curr.Value = "Positions" Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "Site", vbTextCompare) > 0) And Not InStr(1, curr.Value, "ERK") > 0 Then
        Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'puts dashes in any blank cells in the columns
n = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
For Each curr In Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & n)
    If curr.Value = "" Then curr.Value = " - "
Next
For Each curr In Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E" & n)
    If curr.Value = "" Then curr.Value = " - "
Next
For Each curr In Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G" & n)
    If curr.Value = "" Then curr.Value = " - "
Next
```

Comment: Gather your list of filenames first, *then* start the loop. `*.xls` matches the Excel lock files (`~file.xls`). If you turn of error handling anywhere, don't.

Comment: @Comintern does that mean just moving one line ("Set wb = Workbooks.Open...")  to before "Do While"? I think that's the only code that gathers filenames after the loop starts.

Comment: No, that would only open the first workbook.  Make 2 loops - one to create an array of filenames, the second iterating over that array and opening\processing them.

Comment: @Comintern I'm not so sure how to do that. In answers below, could you post what you have in mind?

Comment: Do all your excel files end exactly like .xls? Are none of them .xlsx? I don't see anything wrong with how you are looping through the files in the folder you enter other than the fact that I don't see where you increment n. Provide the entire macro and I will see if I spot anything wrong.

Comment: As Michael mentions try changing `Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")` to `Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")` this should help it find xlsx and xlsm files as well.

Comment: @Michael all the files are Excel 1997-2003 workbooks, which I believe is .xls  
And when I changed it to "*.xls*" from "*.xls" I got a "subscript out of range error"

Comment: @Michael actually the error must be from something else

Comment: I added the macro.

Answer (score 0):

You should and clean up your code by providing which worksheet you are working on.

```
set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
with ws
    For Each curr In .Range("A" & i, "Z" & i)
        If InStr(1, curr.Value, "Protein name", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "description", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "Common name", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            .Range(curr.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns (version 2)").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
end with
```

I would never use ActiveSheet.

```
n = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

Try this instead

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,"D").End(xlUp).Row
```

I hope this help. I can't really test it on my machine since I don't have Excel installed.